# apache deny directive

Tags: apache-2.2, deny

I am using apache deny to deny a country's ip ranges(Turkey in this case).
However from the apache log I still see ips from .tr(using dls connection presumably) accessing and get a valid http 200 response:
dslxxx.xxx-xxxxx.ttnet.net.tr
what am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

blocking countries via IP address is problematic, not all ip address ranges are allocated on a country basis. If your users are using proxies in different ip ranges, they will still be able to access your server. You should think of another way of controlling access such as strong authentication.